Problema al comparar datos al ingresar
Muy buenas a toda la comunidad, esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, miren realizando las pruebas y fallos de mi primera app en Android Studio, por ejemplo al momento de ingresar los datos en la tabledlayout realizo la búsqueda de datos ya ingresados para con esta tabla a través de la patente del vehículo, por ejemplo en la primera fila ingreso "Reparar Capot" y después en la cuarta o segunda fila dependiendo del caso se ingresa nuevamente "Reparar capot" para todos son iguales por lo cual están repetidos pero al llevarlo al php tengo este código:
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$Mano = $_GET['Mano_Mobra'] ?? NULL;
$Patente = $_GET['Patente_Vehiculo'] ?? NULL;
// Usamos COLLATE para comparación sin distinguir mayúsculas/minúsculas
$consulta = "SELECT Patente_Vehiculo, Mano_Mobra, Activo 
         FROM presupuesto1 
         WHERE Mano_Mobra COLLATE utf8_general_ci = '$Mano' 
         AND Patente_Vehiculo COLLATE utf8_general_ci = '$Patente' 
         AND (Activo = 1)";
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (mysqli_num_rows($datos) > 0) {
    echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Este detalle ya fue ingresado para esta patente de vehículo"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Este detalle no ha sido ingresado aún"));
}
mysqli_close ($conexion);
?>

y este mismo al llevarlo al ide del Android lo tengo así:
private void buscar4(){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.91/gestion/buscar_presupuesto18.php?Mano_Mobra=" + txtdetalle.getText().toString() + "&Patente_Vehiculo=" + g.getText().toString();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");
                if (mensaje.equalsIgnoreCase("Este detalle ya fue ingresado para esta patente de vehículo")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Este detalle ya fue ingresado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    txtdetalle.setText("");
                    txtvalor.setText("");
                    txtvalor.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.91/gestion/insertar_presupuesto1.php");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de red. Por favor, verifica tu conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error del servidor. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de autenticación. Por favor, verifica tus credenciales", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de parseo. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No se pudo establecer conexión. Por favor, verifica tu conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tiempo de espera agotado. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error desconocido. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

ya que como mencione anteriormente se graba de todas maneras, en resumen se graba la primera fila "Reparar Capot", pero después como dije se ingresa "Reparar capot", y lo graba lo cual no puede ser, estuve leyendo e investigando pero todas decían lo mismo en grabar los datos en minúsculas, es decir ingresar "Reparar Capot" y grabarlo así "reparar capot", y después cuando lo ingreso el "Reparar capot" este en Android lo realiza en miniatura y lo compara, pero esto no debe ser ya que con el reporte se ve feo que todo el detalle este en minúsculas,  o lo otro todo en mayúsculas, también es feo, por lo cual veo si hay solución a este disyuntiva que se me presento ojala que me puedan ayudar, y desde ya muchas gracias.

Hola. En el planteamiento de la pregunta no queda claro cuál es el problema. Veo que en la comparación usas utf8_general_ci, eso significa que hará una comparación del tipo case insensitive (eso es lo que significa ci al final), es decir, sin tomar en cuenta acentos, mayúsculas, minúsculas, etc. Además, en Android usas equalsIgnoreCase, lo cual también ignorará mayúsculas / minúsculas. Pero ¿cuál es el problema exactamente?

@A.Cedano muy buenos días, disculpa por la demora en contestar ya qu estaba con probemas de salud y se me hacia imposible contestar, lo que quiero es lo siguiente como te explicaba, mira en Android Studio ingreso "Reparar Capot" el cual esta bien pero si posteriormente el usuario u otro lo haga ingresa así "Reparar capot", por lo cual debe enviar el mensaje que ya esta ingresado para esta patente, pero en Netbeans para Windows lo hice bien y no me da problema alguno si es solo en Android, y esta el código de como hacerlo no se cae, pero no hace lo mencionado anteriormente.

Te deseo una pronta recuperación en cuanto a tus problemas de salud. Con respecto a la pregunta, no queda claro aún cuál es la comparación que falla. Si dices que en unos contextos funciona y en otros no, entonces depura el código allí donde falla. A veces, sobre todo cuando hay entradas de los usuarios, debes sanear / limpiar esas entras. Se me ocurren dos posibles causas del problema: 1. Se están colando cosas como espacios de más en blanco, saltos de línea, saltos de carro, etc, lo cual hace que los datos no coincidan; 2. Una codificación diferente en alguno de los contextos.

Si la causa del problema fuese lo mencionado en 1 podrías resolverlo fácilmente aplicando las funciones de limpieza propias del lenguaje en el contexto en que el código está fallando, son las funciones llamadas trim() y similares. Para depurar el posible error mencionado en 2 puedes verificar con algún editor la codificación del contenido que se está generando, o, mejor aún, verificar la longitud del contenido. Supongamos que al revisar Reparar capot ves que tiene un tamaño distinto a 13 carácteres, entonces, sería evidencia de un problema de codificación.

@A.Cedano muchas gracias por tus palabras, de acuerdo a lo que mencionas que puede ser problema de espacio, lo voy a hacer así que compare con los espacios primero ya tengo ingresado "Reparar Capot" por ejemplo, ahora ingresare "Reparar capot" y que los compare por espacio, si lo que cambia es el del "Capot" por "capot" que los compare pienso ya sea por mayúscula o minúscula puede ser eso que no estoy haciendo en Android,  lo vere y te comento ya que ahora estoy con las pruebas y fallos de los pagos y quiero terminar esto y después vuelvo a de los presupuestos.
